# Django generic view, check if request is in the same group as creator

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-3.7, django-generic-views, django-2.2

Im searching for a way to check user groups when request User is in the same group as the Creator then access and when not then access declined.

The reason behind this is that not every Staff Member may edit all contributions. Only if the staff member is in the same group as the author, then the staff member may edit the article.

My View:

```
class EditArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article
    message = _("Your Article has been updated.")
    form_class = ArticleForm
    template_name = 'articles/article_update.html'


def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user

    return super().form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self):
    messages.success(self.request, self.message)
    return reverse('articles:list')

'''
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(EditArticleView, self).get_queryset()
    queryset = queryset.filter(user=self.request.user)
    print(self.request.user)
    return queryset
'''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you might also consider using the UserPassesTest mixing as described in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin

class EditArticleView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):

    def test_func(self):
        article = self.model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return Group.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(user=article.author).exists() # Or any other test you need

    # ... Your other view code
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed to `==`. But its not working, Django say `Permission denied`. When I print `elf.request.user.groups` and `article.author.groups`, both I get `none` as result. I double checke testuseres, both are in the same Group. One as Memeber and one as Staff

Comment: Sorry for the typo. You did not say what you mean by 'groups'. Are you using the build in groups?

Comment: I mean with groubs my own created User-Groups in the admin Backend

Comment: @Sama Updated my code to meet your environment as I understood it

Comment: The same, Permission denied. I crosschecked         `print(Article.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).user.groups)` says `None` and `print(Group.objects.filter(user=self.request.user))` display the correct group of the logged in User

Comment: What does ```print(Article.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')).user.groups.all())``` print out?

Comment: Then both show the same Group name, but Permission denied

Comment: If ```user``` is the field in your ```Article``` showing the owner: You did adapt the query in the test_fucn accordingly, that is the second filter is ```.filter(user=article.user)```?

Comment: Solved, thank you. There was a misstake from some todays tests. get_queryset was not longer outcomment.